# Database problem (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm trying to create a database with 4 columns(name,contact,date,mail) and i want to insert the values at a time with using array.

`String[] name = {"raja","ravi", "ram"};
String[] contact = {"12345", "123457", "123478"};
String[] date = {"27 jul 2011", 28 Jul 2011"};`

how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First see how to create a database and how to create table in the database.Forget about your string array.Once you can create,open database then see insert,delete,update,select operation.Proceed step by step.

Try to give some effort first and then ask people for the solution

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx) is a nice example of creating a sqlite database and querying to the database.